# Execute mocked jest callback argument

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to execute an argument that is a callback of a jest mock.

In the jest documentation, their callback example is about testing the first callback. I have behaviors inside nested callbacks I need to test. In the examples of promises, they use `resolves` and `rejects`. Is there anything like this for nested callbacks? I'm currently executing the mocked call argument, which I'm not sure if it is the recommended way.

System under test:

```
function execute() {
  globals.request.post({}, (err, body) => {
    // other testable behaviors here.
    globals.doSomething(body);
    // more testable behaviors here. that may include more calls to request.post()
  });
}
```

The test:

```
globals.request.post = jest.fn();
globals.doSomething = jest.fn();

execute();

// Is this the right way to execute the argument?
globals.request.post.mock.calls[0][1](null, bodyToAssertAgainst);

expect(globals.doSomething.mock.calls[0][1]).toBe(bodyToAssertAgainst);
```

My question is in the comments in the code above. Is this the recommended way to execute a callback, which is an argument of the mocked function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't care about the implementation of your `globals.request.post` method you need to extend your mock a bit in order for your test to work.

```
const bodyToAssertAgainst = {};
globals.request.post = jest.fn().mockImplementation((obj, cb) => {
    cb(null, bodyToAssertAgainst);
});
```

Then you can go onto expect that `doSomething` was called with `bodyToAssertAgainst`. Also, this way you can easily test if your `post` would throw an Error.

Comment: Thanks, in the scenario that there may be a nested call to another `request.post()` that I need to also make some asserts against, how would I do that?

In my current code, I would have `globals.request.post.mock.calls[1][1](...)` to simulate executing the second post call.

Comment: I just saw `mockImplementationOnce`. I'm going to check this out and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, you can use that to chain implementations.